# jQuery core doesn't work on Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have a application, which uses jquery script. It works fine on my local webstorm server.
But when I upload it to wordpress - it doesn't work. I have no idea why.

Here is how I connect my jquery code:

```php
wp_enqueue_script( 'rt_calcA_jqueryl', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/CalculatorAccidents/jQuery/jQuery.js', null, '1.0.0', false );
```

The code is in `noConflict` mode. Here is the snippet:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      jQuery('#resultK').click(function(e) {
            var isValid = true;
            jQuery('input[type="number"]').each(function() {
                  if (jQuery.trim(jQuery(this).val()) === '') {
                    isValid = false;
                    jQuery(this).css({
                      "border": "1px solid red",
                      "background": "#FFCECE"
                    });
                  } else {
                    jQuery(this).css({
                      "border": "",
                      "background": ""

                    });
```

Comment: Console errors?

Comment: @ mplungjan There is no errors ..

Comment: In your page source see the url of the js and hit on it and see if it is outputting the correct jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery is added in core `include` folder. So you can enable jQuery by adding following code.

`wp_enqueue_script('jquery');`

Comment: But I have several applications and each uses its own jquery code. That's why I indicate the path to the file.